# ASP.NET MVC4 Controller with OnException not working if inheriting BaseController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, aop

I have a `UsersController`, with `OnException` (which works), but if I make the `Controller` inherit from `BaseController`, the `OnException` doesn't work, even if I put it in the `BaseController`.

Basically I want to have all my controllers inherit from `BaseController` so I can just have one `OnException` handler there, which catches everything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to inherit from a custom base controller class in order to have all controllers handle exceptions the same way. You can do it with an ActionFilter.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, 
    AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // do custom exception handling here
        // to return View("Error"), you can just do this:
        context.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };
    }
}
```

You can apply this to all of the controllers in your library with this Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); // default MVC setting
    filters.Add(new CustomHandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, its working :). brilliant. One question, how can I show my erorr view page from OnException? I cannot call View("Error") anymore because I'm not in a controller

Comment: @baconbeastnz might I suggest you ask that as another question. I for one am curious as to the answer

Comment: @Baconbeastnz and @Bryan Ross, I have updated my answer. Just about anything you can do from a controller, you can do from an action filter, you just have to do it a little differently. `return View("Error")` is just a method on `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` that constructs a `ViewResult` object. I suggest you download the MVC source code and have a look at it. You can always use it as a reference to figure out how to do stuff like this.

Comment: @danludwig, in this way you can't change the model (no setter). How can you transfer a model to your view?

Comment: @Shahar, you can add a model to the ViewResult when you construct it. `new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error", ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new MyCustomViewModel()) }`